# Add some property to cell view( make it open by default)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a list with cells, but only one should be expanded by default. Here is my code with cell view:

```
case .disclaimer(let disclaimer):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: InfoBubbleTableViewCell.self)
            cell.iconImageName = disclaimer.iconName
            cell.titleText = disclaimer.title
            cell.descriptionText = disclaimer.description
            cell.infoBackgroundColor = disclaimer.backgroundColor
            cell.txtColor = disclaimer.textColor
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            return cell
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have now:
[image]
And what I want to have:
[image]

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of `InfoBubbleTableViewCell`s definition. It's possible that you just need to change its `init` so that it starts off in the "opened" state.

Comment: *"I have a cell with a description section..."* -- does this mean you have **multiple** cell classes? And you have only **one** row where you want this cell? And you want it to start "opened" while allowing the user to open/close it? Or... do you have **many** rows with this cell class? Please try to provide a more complete description of what you're doing / trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So, I added the following code, and it works for me

```
cell.isExpanded = true
```

Comment: But cells get reused and as the user scrolls, a collapsed cell will automatically get expanded. Is that what you want?

Comment: No. I want to show the user, by default, open only one section with a description. @HangarRash